# Sitecore - Dynamic values based on url

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm looking to build a site that has a single page but will be displayed no matter what the url is and depending on the url, there will be different peices of information changed.

For example: the phone number.

site.com/url1 - shows 800-123-4567

site.com/url2 - shows 800-456-1234

site.com/url3 - shows 800-987-6543

Can SiteCore 6 do this out of the box or do I need to build a custom control?

Can anyone point me in the right direction of some good tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description and comments it looks like there are several different things you may be trying to do. Essentially though, you want to provide a mechanism for addressing a piece of data stored in Sitecore and presenting/processing it in the same way as the other similar bits of data. As Michael notes above, this isn't just out of the box functionality for Sitecore, it's the basic premiss of the software. If you have, for instance, a phone book, then create a PhoneBookEntry template, associate it with a layout and controls using __Standard Values and then create PhoneBookEntry items from it. Each will be directly addressable without using a querystring.

If your phone number is only part of a wider data set you wish to present (Contact Details, for instance) then you can build a ContactDetails template that uses both an Address template and a PhoneBookEntry template as base templates and then create ContactDetails items from it - they will have all the fields included in Address and PhoneBookEntry. Again, these will be directly addressable without a querystring.

You will always have to create some form of presentation component - whether it's XSLT or .Net - in order to render your content, though this is very simple if you just use the standard Sitecore tools for the job, such as FieldRenderer.

If your ContactDetails wished to allow for multiple phone numbers and you wished to choose which to display then you might want to use the querystring to do so (e.g. show=mobile|office|home). This is a conditional rendering and you will have to insert your querystring test into your presentation component. Again, this doesn't have to be difficult.

The one are where using a querystring might be really advantageous would be if you were using it to lookup data held and maintained outside Sitecore (e.g. a ContactDetails database), though here you would need a custom component anyway.

Remember that your data architecture is really important in Sitecore. It **isn't** a relational database, so designing your architecture to cope with e.g. many to many relationships requires a bit of thought.

It's also worth noting that using querystrings can have a nasty effect on SEO, so its best to keep them to a minimum and where you do use them keep the parameters as few as possible. It's also worth noting that if you start to manipulate link building outside of Sitecores out of the box API you risk that changing a setting in your web.config concerning how links are built and interpreted could break your link. There's a lot of functionality in Sitecore for determining e.g. language of an item that you'd need to replicate if you hand-stitched the links.

I recommend spending some time with the product documentation, there are plenty of cookbooks [there](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Reference/Sitecore%206.aspx).

Aside from the Presentation cookbooks [this](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Dynamic%20Links.aspx) might also be of interest:

Comment: SDN is a joke. Contains mostly references to SiteCore 5. Tried some of the cookbooks but didn't get far because of the version differences.

Comment: @DustinDavis - if you go in through the link above then all the references are for Sitecore 6. There's a fair amount of version difference within 6 though - 6.4 is a fairly major change to e.g. 6.2. I cant find a full API reference though, which I'd like, see my Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757774/what-inbuilt-parameters-can-i-access-in-sitecore-xslt-how-should-i-expose-global

Comment: Yes, we saw 6.4 demo yesterday and it is a big difference. The sales rep said they were working on getting the SDN updated with new documentation. Hopefully they get right to 6.4

Comment: I've not had a chance to play with it yet, but it looks like it's going to make simple a lot of the things that are causing me a headache in 6.2. Sitecore is extremely flexible, and it has a lot of ways of doing things, but it also alows you to do reeeeaally stupid things that you'll regret later... There are a few decent Sitecore blogs out there (Yan has one, so does Mark!) and plenty of devs about on SO and SDN Forum. Before you start customising make sure you have the basics down! Play first, design later :-)

Answer (score 2):

Each of those different URLs is in fact a different page and unique items in the tree in Sitecore. Each would be based on the same template (fields to fill data into) and they'd all have the same layout (.aspx web form), they'd just have different values filled into the fields. This is basic Sitecore functionality.

Comment: Yep, this is probably the way to go if you don't want to build a custom control.  However... how many different URLs are you looking at?  That will affect the best strategy.

Comment: +1. @DustinDavis, your questions made me think you should have deeper understanding of the basic Sitecore concepts before moving forward... Follow the links given by James and spend some time gaining more understanding :)

Comment: @Yan I agree. I only just started SiteCore but I need to know if what I want is possible out-of-the-box or not. The sales reps are selling the moon and aren't all that helpful. The SDN is a joke. I can go off and create all custom components to do what I want but what would be the point of having SiteCore then? That's where I'm at.

Answer (score 1):

Search in our documentation for Sharing Content and Wildcard items.
You'll find the solution in there.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use some URL Rewriting.  That would allow you to take this:

http://site.com/?code=url1

into:

http://site.com/url1

A simple database table with the url to # lookups would then be used to display the correct phone number.

A quick Google search reveals that you will probably need to install something like the Helicon Tech's ISAPI_Rewrite module (http://www.isapirewrite.com/) for URL Rewriting to work in Sitecore.

Here's a blog of someone who did it for extensionless URLs

http://thebackshop.posterous.com/extensionless-urls-with-sitecore-using-the-he

Comment: actually I dont care about url rewriting. It will end up being a querystring url. Can SiteCore show different values based on the url? Is it configurable through SiteCore or do I need to write custom code?

Comment: Acutally, I was offering a solution that would work.  I understand how SiteCore is setup.  He could simply create content pages url1...urlx with the phone number as a data item.  But that seems like a lot of work to me.

Comment: Dustin: URL Rewriting works as though you are recieving a get param for a single page.  Basically, if you can get your solution to work with: http://site.com/?code=url1 then url rewriting helps you map urls like this: http://site.com/url1 to urls like this: http://site.com/?code=url1

Comment: Yan: From his question: "I'm looking to build a site that has a single page but will be displayed no matter what the url is and depending on the url, there will be different peices of information changed."  -- That is the definition of what URL Rewriting does for you.  Why is my answer so far off?  I don't appreciate the vote down.