# I'm trying to for loop through the sitecore templates instead of the items

Tags: xslt, xpath, sitecore

Ok so this is my xslt for looping through the items of the home item, but I would like to be able to loop through the template... The reason for this is so that my xslt can be more specific instead of showing everything under the home item

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="main">
  <div id="aside">
    <ul id="nav">
      <xsl:for-each select="$home/descendant-or-self::item[position() &lt;= 6]">

        <li>
          <sc:link>
            <sc:text field="Title"></sc:text>
          </sc:link>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>

  <div class="advertisement">
    <sc:image field="Image"></sc:image>
  </div>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What does the source XML look like?

Comment: Which templates do u want to include? Is this xslt rendering just the left navigation?

Answer (score 3):

From your xslt it seems you are talking about the navigation. Instead of looping through different templates I would create a specific Navigation template that has only one field called ShowInNavigation. 
Then all your other templates will inherit this one and the navigation xslt will become simpler

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="main">
  <div id="aside">
    <ul id="nav">
      <xsl:for-each select="$home/descendant-or-self::item[sc:fld('ShowInNavigation') = '1']">

        <li>
          <sc:link>
            <sc:text field="Title"></sc:text>
          </sc:link>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>

  <div class="advertisement">
    <sc:image field="Image"></sc:image>
  </div>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Also don't use *descendant-or-self::item* in the navigation because as the site grows the navigation will become your bottleneck.
Better use *$home/item[sc:fld('ShowInNavigation') = '1']* and then hardcode the home node above. So the xslt will become:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="main">
  <div id="aside">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li>
          <sc:link select="$home">
            <sc:text field="Title"></sc:text>
          </sc:link>
        </li>
      <xsl:for-each select="$home/item[sc:fld('ShowInNavigation') = '1']">

        <li>
          <sc:link>
            <sc:text field="Title"></sc:text>
          </sc:link>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>

  <div class="advertisement">
    <sc:image field="Image"></sc:image>
  </div>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Though if you have a multiple site solution then hardcoding the home node in XSLT isn't a possible solution. Better to find some way of passing context information to the XSLT. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757774/what-inbuilt-parameters-can-i-access-in-sitecore-xslt-how-should-i-expose-global

Comment: James if you have multiple sites you can define the `$home` the following way `<xsl:variable name="home" select="$sc_item/ancestor-or-self::item[@template='home']" />` where the home node has 'home' as template

Comment: thank you James I actually figured that out, thank you so much for your input.